# What's the difference between passing this vs. ClassName.this from an event handler when passed to Intent constructor?

Tags: java, android, event-handling, commonsware

In the earlier Android Programming Tutorial, page 192, we see an implementation of `LunchList#onOptionsItemSelected`. Within this implementation we see two `Intent`s passed to `startActivity`: one whose constructor is passed `LunchList.this`, the other whose constructor is passed `this`.

What's the difference?

[See lines 78 - 91 here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/blob/master/14-Rotation/LunchList/src/apt/tutorial/LunchList.java). Note how `onOptionsItemSelected` is not declared within an inner class.

In Android/Java does the value of `this` change within the context of event handlers or function binding via reflection? Could both `Intent` instances be passed `this`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Java, `this` refers to the containing class, and `ClassName.this` refers to the first containing class whose name is `ClassName`.  Event handlers are typically written as anonymous, inner classes, so if you want to refer to the event handler's containing class (and not the event handler's class), you need to specify `ContainingClass.this`, not `this`.

Reference:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4

Comment: I've added a link to the source in question. Note that `onOptionsItemSelected` is not declared within an inner class.

Comment: In that case, the class name is superfluous/redundant.

Answer (score 3):

When you are creating an `Intent` inside an `Inner Class` use `ClassName.this`(here className must be the Activity class Name) and if creating `Intent` inside an `Activity` class you can use `this`.

Comment: I've added a link to the source in question. Note that `onOptionsItemSelected` is not declared within an inner class

Comment: You can also use `this` in place of `LunchList.this`.

Comment: Meaning, there is no difference in this case?

Comment: Yes,because you are creating the `Intent` inside the top level class

Comment: That's what I thought, but I've been hacking around with a "sketch" trying to see about using the reflection API... but I do realize that in Java, this always means "the instance itself." Now my question is, why was it written this way? There are other examples in the text that use ClassName.this within non-inner class methods. Hm.

Comment: Why was it written this way?  Possibly the code was in an inner class where the `ClassName.this` was necessary, and then later refactored to be in the top-level class itself.

Answer (score 1):

For this example it will make no difference as in either condition the class that will start the activity will remain same. First parameter of the Intent refers to the context of the class from where the activity will be launched and from where the bundle data will be passed.