# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException on custom dialog

Tags: android, exception, window-managers, customdialog

My application crashes with below error stack on specific android version and device (VIVO with android 5.1 & Oneplus one with Android 7.1)

```
*_ android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView (ViewRootImpl.java:679)
  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView (WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView (WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
  at android.app.Dialog.show (Dialog.java:329)
  at com.yathirajjp.brainstimuli.QuickMath.showCustomDialog (QuickMath.java:193)
  at com.yathirajjp.brainstimuli.QuickMath$3.onFinish (QuickMath.java:252)
  at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage (CountDownTimer.java:127)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6186)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:889)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:779) _*
```

The code snippet from QuickMath.java as follows

```
final Dialog customDialog = new Dialog(**this**);
customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);

waitTimer.cancel();  // Cancelling the CountDownTimer before calling the show custom dialog

customDialog.show();
```

I suspect the initialisation of customDialog.  Am I right in using the context as 'this'?

Comment: If you are showing dialog in click listener then you need to use `YourActivity.this`. If not, it should works as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TrickySolutions . It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:

You should call **`YourActivity.this`** instead of **`this`**.

**Don't**

```
final Dialog customDialog = new Dialog(this);
```

**Do**

```
final Dialog customDialog = new Dialog(QuickMath.this);
```

Comment: Please accept my sincere apology for delayed response.  I'm still very new to stack overflow. I wasn't sure where the tick sing mark is. :).

Comment: The same issue reported again in new devices now, after making the suggested changes.  Any help please?

Comment: Could anybody explain why it is working like that? What is the difference between `this` and `Class.this` ?

Comment: @AlexanderAgeychenko https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594229/whats-the-difference-between-passing-this-vs-classname-this-from-an-event-hand